# accessing Y columns with duplicated names in j of X[Y, j] merges

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose I have data like this:

```
set.seed(1)
DT <- data.table(id=rep(1:3,each=3),y=1997L+sample(1:9,9))
DT2<- data.table(id=1:3,y=1997L+sample(1:3,3))
```

I want to use DT2$y after merging with DT. I see that this column is named `y.1` after the merge

```
setkey(DT,id)
names(DT[DT2])
# [1] "id"  "y"   "y.1"
DT[DT2][,y.1]
# [1] 1998 1998 1998 2000 2000 2000 1999 1999 1999
```

However, I cannot use it with that name in `j`:

```
DT[DT2,y.1]
# Error in `[.data.table`(DT, DT2, y.1) : object 'y.1' not found
```

What is the secret prefix or postfix that I should be using here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
DT[DT2, i.y]
```

and if you find yourself surprised that it's not the same output as `DT[DT2][, y.1]`, see [this thread](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/changing-data-table-by-without-by-syntax-to-require-a-quot-by-quot-td4664770.html)

Comment: Ah, thanks. That's the expected/desired behavior, as far as my uses go. I don't see `.1` or `i.` in the documentation (`?"[.data.table"` data.table 1.8.8), though I think I saw it before. I wonder why they aren't both named `i.`...