# data.table join then add columns to existing data.frame without re-copy

Tags: r, join, reference, copy, data.table

I have two `data.tables`, X (3m rows by ~500 columns), and Y (100 rows by two columns).

```
set.seed(1)
X <- data.table( a=letters, b=letters, c=letters, g=sample(c(1:5,7),length(letters),replace=TRUE), key="g" )
Y <- data.table( z=runif(6), g=1:6, key="g" )
```

I want to do a left outer join on X, which I can do by `Y[X]` thanks to:

[Why does X[Y] join of data.tables not allow a full outer join, or a left join?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12773822/why-does-xy-join-of-data-tables-not-allow-a-full-outer-join-or-a-left-join)

But I want to add the new column to `X` *without* copying `X` (since it's huge).

Obviously, something like `X <- Y[X]` works, but unless `data.table` is far cleverer than I give it credit for (and I give it credit for quite a lot of deviousness!), I believe this copies the whole of `X`.

`X[ , z:= Y[X,z]$z ]` works, but is kludgy and doesn't scale well to more than one column.

How do I store the results of a merge back into the retained data.table in an efficient (both in terms of copies and in terms of programmer time) way?

Comment: you don't need to do `Y[X,z]` (and will possibly run into problems doing that if you forget about by-without-by), just `X[, z := Y[X]$z]` works and seems to be faster for this example; although ultimately `X = Y[X]` is by far the fastest of the different expressions I've tried so far

Comment: Interesting.  I had the `,z` in there because I thought that would give DT info about what variables it needed to retain since it optimizes on that.  But your (deleted) point is worth copying here: "watch out for hidden by-without-by when doing smth like `Y[X,z]`."  Even if it's fast, if `X = Y[X]` creates a copy I'm potentially in trouble....

Comment: I see, so your concern is more about memory usage and less speed; in that case I think what you suggested, in the form that you suggested, by-without-by's notwithstanding (ok here I think - I always get confused about it), is probably the way to go

Comment: Do I have to worry about by if I do `Y[X,list(z)]` instead?

Comment: No, you'll only need to worry if you do anything other than list all elements, or more specifically, when the operation is different when done by group

Comment: Got it.  Still leaves `X[, z := Y[X]$z]` still leaves me with the problem of doing it for many variables, unfortunately.

Comment: Related and also answered by eddi albeit without anyone finding the documentation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16843728/accessing-y-columns-with-duplicated-names-in-j-of-xy-j-merges

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is easy to do:

```
X[Y, z := i.z]
```

It works because the only difference between `Y[X]` and `X[Y]` here, is when some elements are not in `Y`, in which case presumably you'd want `z` to be `NA`, which the above assignment will exactly do.

It would also work just as well for many variables:

```
X[Y, `:=`(z1 = i.z1, z2 = i.z2, ...)]
```

---

Since you require the operation `Y[X]`, you can add the argument `nomatch=0` (as @mnel points out) so as to not get NAs for those where X doesn't contain the key values from Y. That is:

```
X[Y, z := i.z, nomatch=0]
```

---

From the [NEWS for data.table](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/NEWS?view=markup&root=datatable)

> ```
>     **********************************************
>     **                                          **
>     **   CHANGES IN DATA.TABLE VERSION 1.7.10   **
>     **                                          **
>     **********************************************
> ```
>
> NEW FEATURES
>
> ```
> o   The prefix i. can now be used in j to refer to join inherited
>     columns of i that are otherwise masked by columns in x with
>     the same name.
> ```

Comment: Many thanks.  That works (even with my edited example data), but I don't understand why.  Is there a name for the `i.` notation?  I don't see it anywhere in `?[.data.table`....

Comment: I think the `i.` usage is poorly documented and I forget where it is right now - but it's simply used to refer to columns of the `i-expression` data.table

Comment: I get it.  Still a little confused as to why `X[Y]` (right outer join) produces such different results from `X[Y, z:= i.z]` (left outer join with assignment).

Comment: they both produce the same result as far as the join goes, and in the second case, the resulting `z` from `Y` is assigned to a new column in `X` (which automatically produces `NA`'s for cases where there was no match)

Comment: Ah I get it. Very clever. Gist of me testing it is here: https://gist.github.com/gsk3/7128419

Comment: @AriB.Friedman -- it is in the NEWS for version 1.7.10 (I've added a link). For the differences, it comes down to the fact you can't add rows by reference (yet), so `X[Y, z:=i.z]` will be the equivalent of setting `z=i.z`  X[Y, z:=i.z, nomatch=0]`

Comment: `nomatch=0` is not meaningful during an assignment, as indicated by the warning shown when running that line of code.

Answer (score 9):

As an addition to the answer above, you can also do (`v1.9.6+`):

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.6+
X[Y, (colNames) := mget(paste0("i.", colNames))]
```

where `colNames` is a character vector listing the columns you want from `Y`. This lets you efficiently select columns to add (define `colNames` from a subset of `names(Y)`) in the case you are adding many columns.

Also, you can combine it with the new `on=` argument (from `v1.9.6+`) as:

```
# ad-hoc joins using 'on=' instead of setting keys
require(data.table) # v1.9.6+
X[Y, (colNames) := mget(paste0("i.", colNames)), on = "g"]
```

---

Credit to akrun for the `(colNames) := mget(colNames)` strategy here: [Update rows of data frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32899580/update-rows-of-data-frame-in-r/32899606#32899606).

Comment: Actually not akrun, rather the guy above you introduced this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30469832/3001626 . So basically both of the answers on this thread are eddi's