# data.table - Selecting by comparing list of columns to list of values

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to write a function which takes a `data.table`, a list of columns and a list of values and selects rows such that each column is filtered by the respective value.

So, given the following `data.table`:

```
> set.seed(1)
> dt = data.table(sample(1:5, 10, replace = TRUE),
                  sample(1:5, 10, replace = TRUE),
                  sample(1:5, 10, replace = TRUE))
> dt
    V1 V2 V3
 1:  1  5  5
 2:  4  5  2
 3:  1  2  2
 4:  2  2  1
 5:  5  1  4
 6:  3  5  1
 7:  2  5  4
 8:  3  1  3
 9:  3  1  2
10:  1  5  2
```

A call to `filterDT(dt, c(V1, V3), c(1, 2))` would select the rows where `V1 = 1` and `V3 = 2` (rows 3 and 10 above).

My best thought was to use `.SD` and `.SDcols` to stand in for the desired columns and then do a comparison within `i` (from `dt[i,j,by]`):

```
> filterDT <- function(dt, columns, values) {
      dt[.SD == values, , .SDcols = columns]
  }
> filterDT(dt, c("V1", "V3"), c(1, 2))
Empty data.table (0 rows and 3 cols): V1,V2,V3
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work, even if only filtering by one column.

I've noticed all examples of `.SD` I've found online use it in `j`, which tells me I'm probably doing something very wrong.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The values in 'dt' and the ones based on the seed are not matching

Comment: Will a join solve your problem? I.e.  supplying a data.table of conditions to the `i` argument to filter rows of `dt`: `dt[data.table(V1=1, V3=3), on=.(V1,V3)]`

Comment: @ScottRitchie, this has to work with an arbitrary number of columns, so I don't know how to convert `(V1=1, V3=3)` to something like `columns = values` (where `columns = (V1, V3)` and `values = (1, 3)`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the 'values' to be `filter`ed are the ones corresponding to the 'columns' selected, we can do a comparison with `Map` and `Reduce` with `&`

```
dt[dt[ , Reduce(`&`, Map(`==`, .SD, values)) , .SDcols = columns]]
```

As a function

```
filterDT <- function(dt, columns, values) {
       dt[dt[ , Reduce(`&`, Map(`==`, .SD, values)) , .SDcols = columns]]
   }

filterDT(dt, c("V1", "V3"), c(1, 2))
#   V1 V2 V3
#1:  1  4  2
```

Or another option is `setkey`

```
setkeyv(dt, c("V1", "V3"))
dt[.(1, 2)]
#   V1 V2 V3
#1:  1  4  2
```

Comment: I've been using `setkey` just when I wanted to join tables. like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/38798400/6461462. While it should be obvious by definition of `key`, I never thought of this. Cheers.

Comment: @M-M See the vignette [Keys and fast binary search based subset](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-keys-fast-subset.html). Instead of setting keys, you can also use the `on` argument; see Examples in `?data.table` ("# fast ad hoc row subsets (subsets as joins")) and [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56263213/data-table-selecting-by-comparing-list-of-columns-to-list-of-values#comment99143267_56263213)

Comment: wrapping the setkey solution in a function as forseen by OP: `filterDT <- function(DT, columns, values) setkeyv(DT, columns)[values]`

Answer (score 4):

I think you should be able to write a function that joins using an arbitrary number of columns:

```
#' Filter a data.table on an arbitrary number of columns
#'
#' @param dt data.table to filter
#' @param ... named columns to filter on and their values
filter_dt <- function(dt, ...) {
  filter_criteria <- as.data.table(list(...))
  dt[filter_criteria, on = names(filter_criteria), nomatch=0]
}

# A few examples:
filter_dt(dt, V1=1, V3=2)
filter_dt(dt, V1=2, V2=2, V3=5)
filter_dt(dt, V1=c(5,4,4), V3=c(1,2,5))
```

Basically the function constructs a new data.table from the arguments supplied to `...`, each argument becoming a column in the new data.table `filter_criteria`. This is then supplied to the `i` argument of `dt` with the column names of `filter_criteria` used as the columns in the join.