# Combining/merging a column in R

Tags: r

I am probably missing something quite easy with this problem. I can't find the proper answer anywhere - and I really need to move on. So I have oversimplified my data:

```
eventID <- c(2,4)
Time <- c("09:32","09:43")
df1 <- data.frame(eventID,Time)
eventID <- rep(c(1:4),rep(3,4))
Time <- rep(c("09:30",NA,"09:40",NA),rep(3,4))
df2 <- data.frame(eventID,Time)
```

What I would like is to combine the `Time` column. So the NAs in `df2` should be filled up with `Time` values from `df1` matching the `eventID`. My original data is quite large so a `for`-loop is not what I am looking for really. I was hoping this would work:

```
> (res1 <- merge(df1,df2, by = "eventID", all = T))
#   eventID Time.x Time.y
#1        1   <NA>  09:30
#2        1   <NA>  09:30
#3        1   <NA>  09:30
#4        2  09:32   <NA>
#5        2  09:32   <NA>
#6        2  09:32   <NA>
#7        3   <NA>  09:40
#8        3   <NA>  09:40
#9        3   <NA>  09:40
#10       4  09:43   <NA>
#11       4  09:43   <NA>
#12       4  09:43   <NA>
```

Desired output:

```
> eventID <- rep(c(1:4),rep(3,4))
> Time <- rep(c("09:30","09:32","09:40","09:43"), rep(3,4))
> (res2 <- data.frame(eventID,Time))
#   eventID  Time
#1        1 09:30
#2        1 09:30
#3        1 09:30
#4        2 09:32
#5        2 09:32
#6        2 09:32
#7        3 09:40
#8        3 09:40
#9        3 09:40
#10       4 09:43
#11       4 09:43
#12       4 09:43
```

Suggestions? If possible in `base` I would prefer that, or `data.table` package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(df2), eventID)[df1, Time:= i.Time][]
#   eventID  Time
#1:       1 09:30
#2:       1 09:30
#3:       1 09:30
#4:       2 09:32
#5:       2 09:32
#6:       2 09:32
#7:       3 09:40
#8:       3 09:40
#9:       3 09:40
#10:      4 09:43
#11:      4 09:43
#12:      4 09:43
```

Or a `base R` option after the `merge` would be

```
 data.frame(eventID= res1[,1], 
     Time=res1[-1][cbind(1:nrow(res1),max.col(!is.na(res1[-1])))])
```

#### Update

Suppose there are some 'eventID' in the first dataset are not in the second ('df2'), then we can specify `nomatch=0`

```
 df3 <- data.frame(eventID= c(2,4,5), Time=c('09:32', '09:43', '09:45'))

 setkey(setDT(df2), eventID)[df3, Time:= i.Time,nomatch=0][]
  #    eventID  Time
  # 1:       1 09:30
  # 2:       1 09:30
  # 3:       1 09:30
  # 4:       2 09:32
  # 5:       2 09:32
  # 6:       2 09:32
  # 7:       3 09:40
  # 8:       3 09:40
  # 9:       3 09:40
  #10:       4 09:43
  #11:       4 09:43
  #12:       4 09:43
```

Comment: Wow, that was easy! I knew it would be. I am trying to understand. Because i got as far as `df2[df1]` myself but it missed the `eventID` 1 and 3. How does `Time := i.Time` work then? I thought that was for copying.

Comment: @tstev If you do `setkey(setDT(df2), eventID)[df1]`, then the `Time` values for the corresponding `i.Time` are `NA` which we are replacing with `i.Time`.  May be this link also give some ideas http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19553005/data-table-join-then-add-columns-to-existing-data-frame-without-re-copy

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answering this easy question!