# Update rows of data frame in R

Tags: r

Suppose I start with a data frame:

```
 ID Measurement1 Measurement2
  1           45          104
  2           34           87
  3           23           99
  4           56           67
...
```

Then I have a second data frame which is meant to be used to update records in the first:

```
 ID Measurement1 Measurement2
  2           10           11
  4           21           22
```

How do I use R to end up with:

```
 ID Measurement1 Measurement2
  1           45          104
  2           10           11
  3           23           99
  4           21           22
...
```

The data frames in reality are very large datasets.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

We can use `match` to get the row index.  Using that index to subset the rows, we replace the 2nd and 3rd columns of the first dataset with the corresponding columns of second dataset.

```
ind <- match(df2$ID, df1$ID)
df1[ind, 2:3] <- df2[2:3]
df1
#  ID Measurement1 Measurement2
#1  1           45          104
#2  2           10           11
#3  3           23           99
#4  4           21           22
```

---

Or we can use `data.table` to join the dataset `on` the 'ID' column (after converting the first dataset to 'data.table' i.e. `setDT(df1)`), and assign the 'Cols' with the 'iCols' from the second dataset.

```
 library(data.table)#v1.9.6+
 Cols <- names(df1)[-1]
 iCols <- paste0('i.', Cols)
 setDT(df1)[df2, (Cols) := mget(iCols), on= 'ID'][]
 #   ID Measurement1 Measurement2
 #1:  1           45          104
 #2:  2           10           11
 #3:  3           23           99
 #4:  4           21           22
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:4, Measurement1 = c(45L, 34L, 23L, 56L), 
Measurement2 = c(104L, 87L, 99L, 67L)), .Names = c("ID", 
"Measurement1", "Measurement2"), class = "data.frame",
 row.names = c(NA, -4L))

df2 <-  structure(list(ID = c(2L, 4L), Measurement1 = c(10L, 21L),
 Measurement2 = c(11L, 
 22L)), .Names = c("ID", "Measurement1", "Measurement2"),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Answer (score 8):

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  anti_join(df2, by = "ID") %>%
  bind_rows(df2) %>%
  arrange(ID)
```

Comment: This also works as a good workaround for rows_upsert() which is having a problems when  duplicates are present

Answer (score 7):

`dplyr 1.0.0` introduced a family of SQL-inspired functions for modifying rows.  In this case you can now use `rows_update()`:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  rows_update(df2, by = "ID")

  ID Measurement1 Measurement2
1  1           45          104
2  2           10           11
3  3           23           99
4  4           21           22
```