# Updating Values in New Data with Old Data

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data frame:

```
library(dplyr)

old_data = data.frame(id = c(1,2,3), var1 = c(11,12,13))

> old_data

  id var1
1  1   11
2  2   12
3  3   13
```

I want to replace the values in the 2nd row of "old_data" with data in "new_data" (i.e. rows in "old_data" where the id variables matches ):

```
new_data = data.frame(id = c(4,2,5), var1 = c(11,15,13))

> new_data

  id var1
1  4   11
2  2   15
3  5   13
```

Using the answer found here ([Update rows of data frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32899580/update-rows-of-data-frame-in-r)), I tried to do this with the "dplyr" library:

```
update =  old_data %>%
     rows_update(new_data, by = "id")
```

But this gave me the following error:

```
Error: Attempting to update missing rows.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

This is what I am trying to get:

```
   id var1
    1  1   11
    2  2   15
    3  3   13
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A little bit messy but this works (on this sample data at least)

```
old_data %>% 
  left_join(new_data,by="id") %>% 
  mutate(var1 = if_else(!is.na(var1.y),var1.y,var1.x)) %>% 
  select(id,var1)

#  id var1
#1  1   11
#2  2   15
#3  3   13
```

Comment: @ Martin : Thank you so much! This worked!

Comment: I'm glad! Please consider marking as accepted when you can. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

A base R approach using `match` -

```
inds <- match(old_data$id, new_data$id)
old_data$var1[!is.na(inds)] <- na.omit(new_data$var1[inds])
old_data

#  id var1
#1  1   11
#2  2   15
#3  3   13
```

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` approach (with turning the data table back into a dataframe):

```
library(data.table)

as.data.frame(setDT(old_data)[new_data, var1 := .(i.var1), on = "id"])
```

**Output**

```
  id var1
1  1   11
2  2   15
3  3   13
```

An alternative `tidyverse` option using `rows_update`. You can filter `new_data` to only have `id`s that appear in `old_data`. Then, you can update those values, like you had previously tried. Essentially, `new_data` must only have `id` values that appear in `old_data`.

```
library(tidyverse)

old_data %>% 
  rows_update(., new_data %>% filter(id %in% old_data$id), by = "id")
```

**Data**

```
old_data <-
  structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3), var1 = c(11, 12, 13)),
            class = "data.frame",
            row.names = c(NA,-3L))
new_data <-
  structure(list(id = c(4, 2, 5), var1 = c(11, 15, 13)),
            class = "data.frame",
            row.names = c(NA,-3L))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `dplyr::rows_update` if we first use a `semi_join` on `new_data` to filter only those `id`s that are included in `old_data`.

```r
library(dplyr)

old_data %>% 
  rows_update(new_data %>%
                semi_join(old_data, by = "id"),
              by = "id")

#>   id var1
#> 1  1   11
#> 2  2   15
#> 3  3   13
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>